# How prove $\int_{S^{n-1}}f(x\cdot \omega)\,d\omega=\int_{S^{n-1}}f(-x\cdot \omega)\,d\omega$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, harmonic-analysis, spherical-harmonics

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function.
I Believe that

$$\int_{S^{n-1}}f(x\cdot \omega)\,d\omega=\int_{S^{n-1}}f(-x\cdot \omega)\,d\omega.\qquad \qquad (1)$$

The reason is $-\omega$ is the unit vector antipodal to $\omega$, and then when we integrate on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ we are summing the same integrand over the same surface.

How can we show this rigorously ?

Well, we change variables $\bar{\omega}=-\omega$, and then the Jacobian is $(-1)^n$. But we do not worry about the minus sign since we can reorient the sphere in the "correct" direction and obtain (1).

How can we write down the math?

Comment: The change of variables formula uses the value of the determinant. Also, your change of variables is $x \mapsto -x$, which, of course, preserves $S^{n -1}$.

Comment: Consider $n=1$. Then $\int_{S^0}f(x\cdot\omega)d\omega=f(x)-f(-x)$, but $\int_{S^0}f(-x\cdot\omega)d\omega=f(-x)-f(x)$. These are in general not equal. Your formula is true only for even $n$, because that's precisely when the antipodal map on the $n-1$-sphere preserves orientation. For odd $n$, they differ by a sign.

Comment: @Charles Hudgins. Of course, by the change of variables $x\rightarrow x$, you mean $\omega\rightarrow -\omega$. And the latter, you are saying, preserves $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Did I get you right ?

Comment: @ Thorgott. You are saying that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x_1\cos{\theta}+x_2\sin{\theta})d\theta=f(x_1,x_2)-f(-x_1,-x_2)$. Are you sure of this formula?

Comment: No, I am talking about $S^0$, not $S^1$.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what is $\mathbb{S}^0$ ?

Comment: The $0$-sphere. That is, $S^0=\{-1,1\}\subset\mathbb{R}$. The standard orientation on $S^0$ has the point $\{1\}$ positively and the point $\{-1\}$ negatively oriented, which is where my above claim comes from.

Comment: @Thorgott. Okay. But $\int_{-1}^{1}f(xy)dy=\int_{-1}^{1}f(-xy)dy$.

Comment: @Medo I made a few typos. The change of variables you need to make is $\omega \mapsto -\omega$ (I wrongly read the integral as being against $x$, not $\omega$. The change of variables formula is $\int_{g(A)} f(x) dx = \int_A f(g(u)) |\det Dg(u)| du$. In your case $g(\omega) = -\omega$ and $A = S^{n -1}$.

Comment: Yes, but we are integrating over $S^0=\{-1,1\}$, not over the unit interval $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Perfect, and, in your notation, $g(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})=\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ where $g(\omega)=-\omega$.

Comment: @Medo yes, that's right.

Comment: @Thorgott I don't think these are oriented integrals. I think when $n=1$  $d\omega$ is a unit point mass at each of $-1,1.$ When $n=1$ it's arc length, $n=2$ it's surface area, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The measure $d\omega$ is surface area measure on $S^{n-1}.$ This measure is rotation invariant. I.e., if $T$ is a rotation (aka orthogonal transformation), then

$$\int_Sf(\omega)\,d\omega = \int_S f(T(\omega))\,d\omega$$

for all such $T.$ Since $T(z)=-z$ is a rotation, we get the result.

Comment: Thanks zhw. Let us get to the details. Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow :\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a rotation. Then there exists an orthogonal matrix $A$ (orthogonal means invertible with orthonormal columns,  $A^{-1}=A^T$, and |det(A)|=1) such that $Tx=Ax$. Now change variables $\bar{\omega}=T\omega=A\omega$. Then $|det(\frac{\partial(\bar{\omega}) }{\partial(\omega)})|=|det(A)|=1$. Hence your inequality. Correct/Any comments ?

Comment: That's basically it. (It's an equality, not an inequality.)

Comment: Yes. Equality. sorry.